# The use of .log.txt file in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql server 5.0

I see there is a file called as log.txt under the path "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\data.log.txt".

What is the use of this logfile?

Comment: what do you see in that log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the general query log, contains a log of all connections and all statements executed. specified with the --log option on the command line:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-log.html